# Parse one-to-many relationship

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I have an `Article` table and a `Comment` table. The `Comment` table has a column that is a `PFPointer` to the `Article` it belongs to.

Is it possible to get all `Articles` as well as # of `comments` each `Article` has in one query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that with Parse. You would have to first get the articles, and then iterate the articles to get the count (using countObjects or similar: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-counting/iOS)

Comment: So if I have N articles, and I want to get the # of comments each article has, I would have to make N queries?

Comment: Yes, with your current model. However, your model may be a little too SQL-ish. There are many ways to handle these things in NoSQL databases that seem odd (or even totally wrong) for people who are used to working with SQL. For a NoSQL headsup, I usually recommend reading about the Twitter clone made with Java and Cassandra (search for "Twissandra" on Google). The way tweeting, following etc is solved there is radically different from the SQL way. And also necessary, as the SQL way would not scale to a service like Twitter